# Cloudformation template throws "Encountered unsupported property Statement"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to construct a Cloudformation template where CloudTrail will store the logs from my VPC in a S3 Bucket. When I try to launch the model, I get a "   Encountered unsupported property Statement" for the bucket policy.

Here is the JSON I use:

```
"LogBucketPolicy": {
        "Type": "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
        "Properties": {
            "Bucket": {
                "Ref": "LogBucket"
            },
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailAclCheck",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "s3:GetBucketAcl",
                    "Resource": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "arn:aws:s3:::",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "LogBucket"
                                }
                            ]
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "Sid": "AWSCloudTrailWrite",
                    "Effect": "Allow",
                    "Principal": {
                        "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
                    },
                    "Action": "s3:PutObject",
                    "Resource": {
                        "Fn::Join": [
                            "",
                            [
                                "arn:aws:s3:::",
                                {
                                    "Ref": "LogBucket"
                                },
                                "/AWSLogs/",
                                "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
                                "/*"
                            ]
                        ]
                    },
                    "Condition": {
                        "StringEquals": {
                            "s3:x-amz-acl": "bucket-owner-full-control"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
```

This template is taken from an AWS [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cloudtrail-trail.html#aws-resource-cloudtrail-trail-examples), therefore I am a bit confused on I made a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for the type `AWS::S3::BucketPolicy`, the expected properties are Bucket and PolicyDocument. In your template, you don't have PolicyDocument. Instead, you have Statement. That should resolve the issue. CloudFormation template references can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html).

Bucket policy snippet (that I am referring to) can be found below:

```
"BucketPolicy" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
  "Properties" : {
    "Bucket" : {"Ref" : "S3Bucket"},
    "PolicyDocument" : {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
```

Comment: Thank you Krishna! Now the “Encountered unsupported property Statement” error is gone, however a new error is raised by CloudTrail... "Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket". Do you have any idea what it could be?

Comment: Please share the complete error. It should probably have more message

Comment: Also, did you add the `Version` in your bucket policy in the template?

Comment: Yes, I did add the Version,   "Version": "2012-10-17" :)

I'm not sure I can find more than the error message displayed in CloudFormation:
5:08:05 UTC+0100 | CREATE_FAILED | AWS::CloudTrail::Trail | Trail | Incorrect S3 bucket policy is detected for bucket: mypile-logbucket-ycijs08eajsv

Comment: Since this is a new problem, can you create a new stackoverflow question and put the relevant template snippet in there. We don't want to have a single question for multiple problems.

Comment: Sure, make sense. Thanks for the help anyway!